# Will I need an ELB to access private ECS Containers or a NAT Instance/Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have just configured Octopus Deploy container in ECS in a private subnet. The database and ECS cluster both are in private subnets. I am using a bastion host to connect to the sql server and I am able to access the containerized octopus deploy web page from the bastion but not from my local computer. Would an ALB solve this or would I need both NAT gateway and elb? Or just a NAT instance? Both? I know I need them in a public subnet but do not want to over or under provision resources for this use case.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you just need to do port forwarding to the bastion?

Comment: Did not think of that. Since ECS Fargate container IPs change when they are stopped and started I figured we'd to put the containers behind an ELB with a static IP. We are able to accomplish this with port forwarding from the bastion as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

- Move the Octopus Deploy ECS task into a public subnet, and assign it a public IP address.
- Create an ALB in a public subnet, that forwards traffic to the ECS container.
- Port forwarding through the bastion host

A NAT Gateway is for outbound traffic originating inside the VPC. It provides your private resources with the ability to connect to the Internet. You are trying to initiate a connection from the Internet, so a NAT gateway won't help with that.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I got it all set up properly now!